# unknown pattern color for the background color attribute

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

Getting the compiler warning:

```
Unsupported Configuration: 
Unknown pattern color for the Background Color attribute
```

on my xib when trying to set the background color of a UIView to clear in interface builder.  I swear I've made a UIView clear in the past without any trouble.  Google isn't giving me anything useful.  I feel like there is a head-slapping-simple answer here but after 14 hours at the keyboard (not on this issue) my tired mind isn't figuring it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had lot of problem with the same issue. I solved this by this way 
 "select the UIView in interface builder, background color first **set default color** in option and build it".

Comment: Finding the offending view can be a problem.  The easy way to do this is to open the xib with a text editor and search for "pattern".  Once you have that, you can look at the enclosing view and work out which view it is.

Comment: That did help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this warning after updating to Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.1

I read elsewhere that the clearColor was the cause of this warning but in my case it was a pattern very similar to the standard Apple dark grey style background you see after updating an iPhone. No idea how it got there, don't remember ever asking for a pattern rather than a color nor how to select a pattern in the color selector popup. Perhaps it was chosen by IB because something in my original code was missing.

I changed it to Default, rebuilt and the warning has not returned.  The only problem was going through each UIView until I found the one causing the warning because the background preview dropbox control in attributes is tiny.

Once aware of it, the pattern can be seen instead of a color

[image: Background selection control]

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a compile time error in XCode 8 (beta). Storyboard wont even open.
So we need to open storyboard in editor mode in XCode 7.x and search for "pattern" text and find the view as suggested by @Gordon Dove and fix it by changing the pattern to a plain color.
[image]